# Issue with Assets 2.0.5

Tags: ee2, pixelandtonic, assets

I am getting an error when I try to load and entry in our EE Install.  I am posting here first as I think it is an Assets issue.  I am running EE 2.5.5 with latest version of MSM.  This is only happening to users accessing this specific entry so far.  As a Super Admin I can access the entry without issues.  Here is the error I am getting. Originally this shows up as a blank white page until I turn debug mode on.  Any help you be appreciated!

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception
'Exception' with message 'Assets could not complete the requested operation.' in 
/home/uuoci/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/assets/sources/ee/file.ee.php:33 
Stack trace: #0 /home/uuoci/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/assets/sources/base_source.php(807
): Assets_ee_file->__construct(1467, Object(Assets_ee_source)) #1 /home/uuoci/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/assets/libraries/assets_lib.php(64
7): Assets_base_source->get_file(1467) #2 /home/uuoci/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/wygwam/helper.php(899): 
Assets_lib->get_file_by_id(Array) #3 /home/uuoci/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/wygwam/ft.wygwam.php(397): 
Wygwam_helper::replace_asset_tags('&lt;h2&gt;??Swi...') #4 /home/uuoci/public_html/system/expressionengine/fieldtypes/EE_Fieldtype.php(242): Wygwam_ft->display_field('&lt;h2&gt;??Swi...') #5 [internal function]: EE_Fieldtype-
>display_publish_field('&lt;h2&gt;??Swi...') #6 /home/uuoci/public_html/system/express in /home/uuoci/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/assets/sources/ee/file.ee.php on line 33
```

Comment: jgengler - is this happening when viewing a template outputting that code? Or in the CP?  A few more speciics here would help.  Also, what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Lisa, sorry for the late reply I got sidetracked on another project.  This happens in the CP only.  And only for non super admin users.  I can see it fine without this error but my users get this error when they are logged in.  The actual template gets output just fine as well.  We are running version PHP 5.5.22

Comment: jgengler - if you re-create the entry (whole new entry, same content) and then visit it in the template, does it error?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to recreate the entry from scrap and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Same, though I'd love to know why this is happening in the first place.

Comment: I just ended up here again, and the problem made sense: a particular Member Group did not have access to a File Upload location that was used in a Wygwam field.